# UI-router change state without changing url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Does anybody know how to change the ui-router state without changing the url? As the code below shows; in some cases the user needs to be redirected to 403 or 401 states. I would like to be able to do this redirect without changing the url.

Regards,
klmdb

```
// make sure authGetCurrent has ran before routing starts
$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeSuccess", function(event, next) {

    event.preventDefault();

    AuthService.loadCurrentAuth().then(function(){

        $urlRouter.sync();
    }, function(){

        console.log("BIG ERROR!!!");
    });
});
// Configures $urlRouter's listener *after* your custom listener
$urlRouter.listen();




$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

    var requiredLogin       = (toState && toState.data ? toState.data.requiredLogin       : false ),
        requiredGroupRights = (toState && toState.data ? toState.data.requiredGroupRights : false );        // require the user to have at least one of these rights in the current group

    if (requiredLogin && !AuthService.isLoggedIn()) {

        event.preventDefault();
        $state.transitionTo('401');
        return;
    }
    if(requiredGroupRights){

        var i,
            hasRight = false;
        for(i=0;i<requiredGroupRights.length;i++){

            if(GroupService.checkGroupRights(toParams.groupId, requiredGroupRights[i])){
                hasRight = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!hasRight){

            event.preventDefault();
            $state.transitionTo('403');
            return;
        }

    }

});
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Pass the `{ location: false }` option to $state.go

```
$state.go("home.foo", {}, { location: false } );
```

See it in action: http://plnkr.co/edit/w2aolrt9wdW3EFcEB3Lw?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module('demonstrateissue', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
  $stateProvider.state({ 
    name: 'home', 
    url: '/home', 
    controller: function() { }, 
    template: '<h1>Home</h1><div ui-view></div>'}
  );
  $stateProvider.state({ 
    name: 'home.foo', 
    url: '/foo', 
    controller: function() { }, 
    template: '<h1>foo</h1>'}
  );
});

// Adds state change hooks; logs to console.
app.run(function($rootScope, $state, $location) {
  $rootScope.$state = $state;
  $rootScope.$location = $location;

  // This function will go to home.foo state but not change url
  $rootScope.gotofoo = function() { 
    $state.go("home.foo", {}, { location: false } );
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.25" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-router@*" data-semver="0.2.13" src="https://rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.13/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="demonstrateissue">

      <div ui-view>/div>  

      <div class="header">
        Current URL: <b>{{$location.url()  }}</b> <br>
        Current State: <b>{{$state.current.name }}</b> <br>
        Current Params: <b>{{$state.params | json }}</b><br>
      </div>

      <!-- click this -->
      <a href ng-click="gotofoo()">Go to foo dont change url</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want not create a function, you can pass a object to the attribute "ui-sref-opts" like following:

```
<a ui-sref="my-page" ui-sref-opts="{location:false}">My Page</a>
```

The following line (present in angular-ui-router.js) show the allowed attributes:

```
var allowedOptions = ['location', 'inherit', 'reload', 'absolute'];
```