# Passing Parse Notification data to IONIC app

Tags: cordova, parse-platform, ionic-framework

Is there any way of passing notification data from a Parse notification to ionic (cordova/phonegap) app?

Answer (score 0):

You mean receive a Parse.com notification on your Application ?? Yeah! Ionic and phonegap use javascript!

- Sign up at Parse.com
- Create an Application at Parse.com
- Copy one JavaScript file
- Copy Application and JavaScript keys
- Write code

Initialize your Parse application:

```
Parse.initialize("app ID", "js ID");
```

After that you should get Parse using its javascript library.

Hope it could be useful =)

Comment: No I don't mean that :) I've done that already. I'm receiving the notification on my app, what i want is to be able to open a specific page based on notification. E.g. if i get a friend request notification, i want to open my friend request page in app when user taps on the notification

Answer (score 0):

## If you're using a hybrid style

You should have parsed the notification in your native part so that you can generate an `NSString` object as the target url.

So you can just use `- (void)loadRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request` in `UIWebView` to open it.

## If you're using the ionic way

Then you are using ui-route to do the route thing.

So you can use `$state.go("your.state", {}, { location: false } );` to change the page.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299311/ui-router-change-state-without-changing-url) to have detail explain.

Comment: Can you explain this in a better way? Perhaps with an example...

"You should have parsed the notification in your native part so that you can generate an NSString object as the target url."

Comment: @AhsanAyaz so what's your received Parse  notification?