# Logout state that doesn't change view

Tags: angularjs

Currently I have a problem with states in AngularJS 1.x.

We've in our application a "logout" state that looks like this:

```
.state('logout', {
        onEnter:function($window) {
            Cookies.remove('cookieTest');
            $window.open('http://url/', '_self');
        }
    })
```

Now the redirect works and also the cookie is getting removed. How ever, as I'm switching states, the ng-view is changing to a blank page. In some cases we've got ng-leave defined in our CSS so also an animation will appear.

Is there a way how we can do the functionallity described above, within the .state() but which will not change the ng-view?

As you can see we tried it firstly with a "onEnter" so it would maybe do the redirect before switching states. We also tried to play with the information posted as accepted answer in this topic: [UI-router change state without changing url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299311/ui-router-change-state-without-changing-url). This only makes sure that the URL doesn't change, but I don't want the ng-view to change.

Who can help me out?

Comment: Add cache:true to state

Comment: Added it but doesn't seem to work. The ng-view is still switching to a blank page and then I'll get redirected to the given URL.

Comment: Try redirect without `angular`. For example `window.open('http://url/', '_self');`

Comment: Doesn't effect the speed of redirecting nor getting ride of the ng-view problem.